# Array of pointers syntax

Tags: c++

Please forgive the potentially poorly worded question, but I'm unsure of how to search for this information as I have no concise way to describe it.  I was looking through some APIs and found some interesting syntax which did not seem to mean what I thought.

```
virtual void CreateThing(HANDLE(*pParameterName)[3]);
```

Now I know this API (details below) wants me to create 3 handles and give them back, e.g.

```
pParameterName[0] = CreateHandle()
pParameterName[1] = CreateHandle()
pParameterName[2] = CreateHandle()
```

However I am having trouble grasping the meaning of the parameter syntax. Is this simply an array of 3 pointers to handles? I suspected so, when I try to use this more familiar syntax to override the function, it does not compile, indicating that they are not the same

```
virtual void CreateThing(HANDLE* pParameterName[3]);
```

In other words **What is the difference between the two declarations?**

P.S.

The real API is CreateSwapTextureSet in [OpenVR for Drivers](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/blob/master/headers/openvr_driver.h)

```
virtual void CreateSwapTextureSet( uint32_t unPid, uint32_t unFormat, uint32_t unWidth, uint32_t unHeight, vr::SharedTextureHandle_t( *pSharedTextureHandles )[ 3 ] ) {}
```

Comment: This is probably closeable as a duplicate, but not as "must have a specific problem and show a minimal example". I see no edits to the question. I'm confused.

Comment: I actually don't see any links that are extremely clear on this, though I haven't read much of @JamesRoot's link. From my brief tests (I always have to check this syntax myself), you can only pass a pointer to a stack array of size 3 of HANDLEs. No dynamically allocated array will do and no stack array of any other size will do. This gives compile-time validation of the array size and documents that they always need 3 inside the function itself. Edit: voted to close with Root's link.

Comment: I agree @JamesRoot, I think the answer to my question is "It is not an array of pointers, it is a pointer to an array of size 3".  I will accept the duplicate closure. Thanks!

Millie thanks for verifying before voting to close

Comment: @Ben The syntax is clearly explained in the 3rd answer.